# When div resizes the sup tag element goes downwards, but I want it to stay upwards only

Tags: html, css

Here is my code snippet

html code:

```
<ul id="chat-messages-list">
            <li class="other-message">
                <span>
                    Other's message
                    <% if(locals.user.name=='Mohit'){ %>
                    <sup>~Hacker</sup>
                    <% }else{ %>
                    <sup>~Mohit</sup>
                    <% } %>
                </span>
            </li>
            <li class="self-message">
                <span>
                    <sup>~<%= locals.user.name %></sup>
                    Hey Mohit, how are things going on mate, everthing good
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

SCSS code:

```
#chat-messages-list{
        list-style-type: none;
        height: 80%;
        padding:0px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        overflow-y:auto;

        li{
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 10px;
            padding-top: 2px;
            width: fit-content;
            height: fit-content;
            max-width: 70%;
        }

        span{
            sup{
                vertical-align:top;
                font-size: smaller;
                position: relative;
                top: -0.2em;
                opacity: 0.5;
                padding-bottom: 10px;
            }
        }

        .other-message{
            background-color: lightcoral;
        }

        .self-message{
            background-color: cyan;
            align-self: flex-end;
        }
    }
```

In this image the first and second div is ok, but as soon as the size of div becomes large I get that subscript coming at the bottom issue.
Check this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hB8c0.png

Comment: Based on your screenshot the issue seems to be with overflowing content being cutoff, not `<sup>`'s vertical alignment changing.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I figured out a round about way of doing it.
Modified html code:

```
<ul id="chat-messages-list">
            <li class="other-message">
                <% if(locals.user.name=='Mohit'){ %>
                <sup>~Hacker</sup>
                <% }else{ %>
                <sup>~Mohit</sup>
                <% } %>
                <span>
                    Other's message is rocking the floor, do you think it is good
                </span>
            </li>
            <li class="self-message">
                <sup>~<%= locals.user.name %></sup>
                <span>
                    Self Message
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Modified SCSS code:

```
 #chat-messages-list{
        list-style-type: none;
        height: 80%;
        padding:0px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        overflow-y:auto;

        li{
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 10px;
            padding-top: 2px;
            width: fit-content;
            height: fit-content;
            max-width: 70%;
            display:flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: flex-end;

            sup{
                vertical-align: super;
                font-size: smaller;
                opacity: 0.5;
                text-align: center;
            }
        }

        .other-message{
            background-color: lightcoral;
        }

        .self-message{
            background-color: cyan;
            align-self: flex-end;
        }
    }
```

This worked for me, the screenshot of working version now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmSVk.png